# C++: friend template class / template non-type parameter

Tags: c++, class, templates, friend, non-type

I want to implement generic graph classes and I am still having problems which narrowed down to the following code:

```
template <class T> class B
{
    template <T> friend class A;
};


template <class T> class A
{
private:
    std::vector<B<T> *> myBs;
};


class C { };
```

This compiles pretty well unless I do something like this:

```
B<C> myB;
```

... which causes the following errors:

```
B.h: In instantiation of ‘class B<C>’:
In file included from A.h:12:0,
             from main.cpp:16:
main.cpp:30:10:   required from here
B.h:15:1: error: ‘class C’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
{
^
B.h:11:11: error: template parameter ‘class T’
template <class T> class A;
          ^
B.h:16:31: error: redeclared here as ‘<declaration error>’
template <T> friend class A;
```

Is my thinking absolutely wrong, am I missing something or is such a construct not possible, messy, odd or a very (...) very awful thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `friend` declaration. I suggest you declare the `A` class first, and then use a simpler `friend` declaration. Like

```
template<class T> class A;

template<class T>
class B
{
    friend A<T>;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether you want to make just `A<T>` a friend of `B<T>`.
Then use Joachim's solution!

If you want to make any A a friend, then you need to do this:

```
template <class T> class B
{
    template<class> friend class A;
};
```

Comment: Good idea, but currently I just want to make A<T> a friend of B<T>